# R - I am looking for a function to Extract the last n digits from a Text variable and Save them in a New variable For thousand of Cases

Tags: r, function

I am looking for a function through which i can extract the last N digits from a Variable and save them in a New Variable in the same dataset. The dataset which i have is in the data.table format. I have around thousand of variables in my data frame so listing the data for some of them:

CaseID   Var1  Var2  Var3

298710     1      1      2

399761     3      1      1

200987     1      5      3

Now, the function which i am looking for is something in which i can enter the number of digits to extract from CaseID variable and it will create a new variable as shown below:

CaseID   Var1  Var2  Var3  Newvar

298710    1     1     2      0

399761    3     1     1      1

200987    1     5     3      7

Please note in my data, the class of CaseID is of Character  type.

if you could help me out here then it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `substr` or `substring`

Comment: Hi Akrun....I am trying to use it but its not successful on my data. Its returning the value in Terms of True and false

Comment: Sorry, it got dupe linked.